# regex expression to find a number of character replacement matches in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb

This is way beyond my regex experience, please help. -

I've had a bit of a look around but can't find an example of this kind.

I'm try to match the lower case name of a user in mongoDB via JS, where any number of characters can be interchanged between i, l and 1 (eye, ell and one)
also between 0 and o  (zero and ohh)

Examples: chris chr1s chrls will match

also: joomla j00mla j0omla jo0mla will match.

and jimbo j1mb0 jlmbo jimb0 will match etc etc

```
var name_lower = "jlmb0";

user_collection.findOne({name_lower : /?some regex?/name_lower}, function(err, doc) {
    if(err) throw err;
    if(doc) {
            // a match
            }
    }
});
```

EDIT: 
Assume lower_name is already parsed as min 3 chars, max 20 chars, [a-zA-Z0-9], and lowered in case, 
Assume it is an input variable, so I have no idea what the user name is.
I guess for performance sake assume there is only 1 or 2 occurrences of the set [o,0] and [i,l]

Assume I have no idea what is inputed into name_lower, does that make it impossible for regex in mongoDB? Perhaps it's easier to just create a set of 12 or so possible names and search for them individually, ie write a function that checks for the two sets and gives out alternative name_lower possibilities?

Comment: FYI: This will be a major performance hit on MongoDB if you're trying to aggressively search every document in a collection for a regex match.

Comment: I understand, so if I forget about '1' can it be qualified to say only 1 or 2 occurrences of the set [i,l] and [o,0] ? and how to do that with a variable of unknown characters. (I've already parsed the variable as [a-zA-Z0-9\.\-], 3-20 characters min/max.

Comment: Could you explain what you're really trying to do? (The "why"?) Unless you "anchor" the regex, it will search through every document, every time, using a regular expression that seems very long and inefficient., possibly just to do fuzzy matching?

Comment: Is there a fuzzy match approach to loading a user name from mongoDB? I would have thought the hit would be the same. Yea just trying to stop similar names from parading as other users, in a chat/game room. Sans serf fonts lower l and upper i look the same.

Comment: No, MongoDb doesn't have a better technique. Here's an example of the complexity and some ideas using ElasticSearch: https://www.found.no/foundation/fuzzy-search/. A regex won't handle something as simple as a character transposition (`stack` and `stakc`). A regex won't return weighted results.

Comment: okay so I thought, might as well just store a special transition name in the DB, converting all i's and l's to 1, and all o's to 0's. Then do the same conversion on the search variable, this will be a one hit only check for the DB, except its not indexed I guess. - I'll go to it, much less stress on the DB :-)